# How to get half-way gate of a two-qubit quantum gate?

Tags: quantum-gate

If I have a quantum gate, how can I get the gate that represents half-way of that gate?  As an example of what I want:
How do I derive $\sqrt {SWAP} $ gate

$$\sqrt {SWAP}  = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & {{{1 + i} \over 2}} & {{{1 - i} \over 2}} & 0  \cr 
   0 & {{{1 - i} \over 2}} & {{{1 + i} \over 2}} & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)$$
from $SWAP$ gate?
$$SWAP = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

Comment: by "half-way" gate do you just mean square root?

Comment: Many versions of this question have been asked.  (I asked one myself recently!)  But I like in particular [this one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3793/arbitrary-powers-of-not-and-swap).

Comment: Thank you all for your attention. The answer that 
Mark S attached is exactly what I was looking for.